# docker swarm: difference between Replicated and Global services

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Based on this picture in this document https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/services/:

[image]

How should the output of the command `#docker service ls` look like for the two services depicted? My understanding is:

```
grey                   global              "1/1"                 consul:latest 
yellow                 replicated          "1/3"                  consul:latest
```

I am not sure about the numbers between "" 
I need support to understand the output

**Correct output based on answer and the picture would be:**

```
 grey                   global              "5/5"                 consul:latest 
 yellow                 replicated          "3/3"                 consul:latest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without placement constraint, a service in global mode will be deployed with one replica on each cluster node. As a result you will have 5/5 replicas.

You can use placement constraints to restrict deployment to specific nodes, for instance to worker nodes or nodes having a specific node label:

- You could use a placement constraint to restrict deployment to your
  worker nodes, which will result in 4 replicas.
- You could add a node label to n of your nodes and use it as placement
  constraint, resulting in n replicas.

While global mode services guaranty that exactly one replica of a service is running on each node that fulfills the placement constraints, the same is not necessarily true for replicate mode services. Replicated mode services are usually fanned out across the nodes, but could also be placed on a single node...

Why do you list the replicas to 1/3 for the (yellow) replicated mode service? If all replicas are deployed successfully it should be 3/3.

The numbers indicates a summary of the total deployment for the service. It does not indicate how the replicas are spread across the cluster, nor where the replicas are running.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. So 3/3 in the case of replicated nodes means that the three services in yellow might be placed on a single worker. Right? So than what could be a meaningful use case for replicated services? I still don’t get the point of distinguishing between global and replicated...

Comment: On 3/3, the left hand side of "/" indicates the number of currently running replicas, while the right hand side of "/" indicates the number of desired replicas. It does not indicate on which node they run. Use `docker service ps {servicename}` to identify on which node the replicas have been scheduled.  A reverse proxy like Traefik would be a good exeample for a global service - it wouldn't make sense to run more than 1 instance per node, would it? Use replicated services, if keeping the number of running instances stable is more important than running each instance on a separate node.